# Why does ruby allow child classes access parent's private methods?

Tags: ruby, oop

```
class Main
    def say_hello
        puts "Hello"
    end
    
    private
        def say_hi
            puts "hi"
        end
end

class SubMain < Main
    def say_hello
        puts "Testing #{say_hi}"
    end

end

test = SubMain.new
test.say_hello()
```

OUTPUT:

> hi
>
> Testing

Comment: It inherits that method. Why do you think it should not be allowed to call it?

Comment: @CanadianCoder I thought in OOP members of a class that are declared private are not inherited by subclasses of that class. At least in Java and PHP that's how it is I believe.

Comment: Just started learning Ruby myself and have to say while reading "The Book of Ruby" this idea seems a little fuzzy if not misleading given the behavior but perhaps that's just me. And yes Java does not allow child classes to access private methods of a super.

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils that's why it's pretty weird to see that behavior in ruby

Comment: @spickermann because that's how OOP behavior usually works. Private methods are private for a reason. Then there is no difference between protected and private methods if we allow child class to access them.

Comment: @CodeCrack: There is a very important difference. Private methods can't be called on a receiver, even if the receiver is `self`. Protected methods can be called on receivers if the receiver is of the same class or an ancestor class. An often quoted example is the comparison: `def <=>(other); self.value <=> other.value; end` must have `value` as either public or protected, since a private value cannot be accessed on another object. Ruby "private" is pretty much what "protected" is in Java; it is a terminology shift.

Comment: I agree that the visibility in Ruby differs from other programming languages like Java for example. But I would not call it wrong therefore. It is just different and you have to learn this differences between languages if you want to master multiple languages.

Comment: And going by what other languages do is not very reliable. PHP silently ignores the `98` in `01398`, producing `11`; there is no reason other languages' parsing of integers should be expected to be similarly bad. Ruby has its own object model, not copied from Java or PHP; it satisfies all the requirements of OO paradigm; and should be learned on its own terms.

Comment: Unrelated - you never have to put parens after your method called like you did with `say_hello()`, as you would in Python or JavaScript. It's considered un-Rubyish

Comment: Voting to close this as opinion based is the equivalent of saying there's no reasoning behind the choice which is madness. Because no one "here" *may* be able to answer definitively doesn't make it opinion based any more than "why doesn't java allow operator overloading"? <= *not opinion!*

Comment: Considering that Ruby is as old as Java and older than PHP, it seems kind of strange to expect that it follow them; unless you have invented a reliable way of time travel, that would simply be impossible.

Comment: Actually stumbled upon this today (private ~ protected).
And I absolutely don't get - why the hell. Is there any way to "patch" it to get "true" private methods? I don't want my subclasses to inherit base class private methods.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The difference is that in ruby you can call private methods in subclasses implicitly but not explicitly. Protected can be called both ways. As for why? I guess you would have to ask Matz.

Example:

```
class TestMain

  protected
  def say_hola
    puts "hola"
  end

  def say_ni_hao
    puts "ni hao"
  end

  private
  def say_hi
    puts "hi"
  end

  def say_bonjour
    puts "bonjour"
  end
end

class SubMain < TestMain
  def say_hellos
    # works - protected/implicit
    say_hola
    # works - protected/explicit
    self.say_ni_hao

    # works - private/implicit
    say_hi
    # fails - private/explicit
    self.say_bonjour
  end
end

test = SubMain.new
test.say_hellos()
```

Answer (score 0):

I am strongly with CodeCrack and very surprised when I found this "private" is not really "private".

I started using Ruby about a year ago. Before that, I used almost all other OOP languages. The most annoying part for Ruby is that it is too "randomly designed" and too much "opinion based", instead of trying to standardize it like C++ and Python, which have principles to follow and you should not expect surprises. Ruby is completely on the other side and I think that is the reason why it is much harder to maintain. Every now and then I have to look around to find out what a weird syntax really means (like many symbol expressions).

A question we should really ask is: why was it this way? What kind of problem it tried to resolve with this way?

The disadvantage is clear to me: now I have to learn what "implicitly" and "explicitly" call mean.

Anyway, a language is a tool which should be easy to use and easy to maintain. I don't think Ruby is going this way.

I personally do not recommend Ruby to anyone else. It should be dumped asap.